# Why don't Android apps run natively on Linux since Android is based on Linux?

Tags: linux, android

So Android itself is a Linux distribution (yes it is). It runs a modified Linux kernel and a stack of other software on top of it.

So I'm wondering - would it be possible if I took my Ubuntu installation, updated the kernel to include what is needed for Android. Also installed all of the Android stack (*Java, Binder, Android runtime, drivers etc.*). Then could it be possible that I could run Android applications on Ubuntu natively?

Comment: Are you thinking of applications that have no GUI then? If not, the kernel might know what to do, but how would you display it on a Linux desktop? An OS is far, far more than just a  kernel.

Answer (score 3):

Android may share the same kernel, but there are more components that an Android app depends on:

[image: the platform architecture stack of an android device]
([Platform Architectures, developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/guide/platform))

Dependencies like the Android Java API or the Android Runtime don't exist on conventional Linux distributions. Without the help of an emulator like the one shipped with Android Studio, Android apps will not be able to run outside its intended platform.